# ndk sigbus adraln after swtich from gcc to clang

Tags: c++, android-ndk, clang

We use r12b ndk with gcc to build our c++ library (with prebuilt library and manually specify flags) and our dependencies (boost 1.66, openssl...etc with standalone toolchain). When we switch to clang (both in r18b and r12b) it starts to have `signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN)` crash ONLY on Nexus 4. I have tried it on Nexus 5X and LG G6 (in armv7 mode) none of them crashes.

ndk-stack says the crash is at
`Routine aligned at /boost/atomic/detail/storage_type.hpp:91` but the message from Undefined Behavior Sanitizer indicates it's already getting misalignment address pointer before it calls boost function.

`runtime error: constructor call on misaligned address 0x9b2a5008 for type 'class1', which requires 16 byte alignment
0x9b2a5008: note: pointer points here`

After adding -Wover-aligned it pops out the message like this.

`error: type 'test1' requires 16 bytes of alignment and the default allocator only guarantees 8 bytes [-Werror,-Wover-aligned]`

and `-fnew-alignment=16 -falign-functions -faligned-new -faligned-allocation` flags help make the warning disappear. But it's still having the same sigbus crash.

I am out of idea. Any guess, suggestion would help. Thanks.

EDIT:
we use api level 21 for ndk.

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Comment: Does `-fnew-alignment` actually change anything, or is it just advice to the compiler? If it's the latter, all you've done is suppress the warning without actually fixing it. It sounds like maybe the wrong type is being allocated, then cast to the proper type and placement new is being called on it? That's undefined behavior if that's the case. When we moved AOSP over to Clang years ago, every `SIGBUS` we hit was undefined behavior, almost always of that form.

Comment: @KimKulling Rn not able to. We are working on the minimal reproducible project.

Comment: @DanAlbert In clang manual it says `Specifies the largest alignment guaranteed by ‘::operator new(size_t)’` so I think it is actually doing something. What I couldn't understand is it only sigbus in nexus 4 (api 22) but not nexus 5X (api 23). They are both using krait arm 32bit CPU.

Comment: yea wrong type casting would be a good direction for us to look into. I do hope it's something at compiler level since gcc works.

Comment: Some ARM instructions are safe for arbitrary alignments and others are not. iirc Clang would use instructions that were not safe for unaligned loads when it could (when the compiler assumes undefined behavior can't possibly happen, loads that can actually be unaligned may be treated this way), presumably because they performed better than those that supported unaligned addresses. GCC did otherwise. Bugs in the compiled code can work differently across compilers, especially when undefined behavior is the cause.

Comment: @DanAlbert Can I ask what's the warning flag you turn on for catching wrong type casting? `-Wundefined-reinterpret-cast  -Wbad-function-cast` are the ones I see in clang. Probably need `-Wold-style-cast` to remove all cast to c++ style static_cast as well.

Comment: I don't think there was a warning for this. Most of what I remember was just debugging crashes :\

Answer (score 1):

We solved this a month ago. Wanna write a quick update in here hopefully can help somebody is having the similar issue.

Here's the stacktrace we were having

---

```
****** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48T/2237560:user/release-keys'
#00 0x002975a8 /data/app/test-2/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so (**redact**)boost::atomics::detail::make_storage_type<1u, false>::aligned::aligned(unsigned char)
/include/boost/atomic/detail/storage_type.hpp:91:85
boost::atomics::detail::base_atomic<bool, int>::base_atomic(bool)
/include/boost/atomic/detail/atomic_template.hpp:496:0
boost::atomics::atomic<bool>::atomic(bool)
/include/boost/atomic/detail/atomic_template.hpp:748:0
```

My team leader pointed me out probably there's something wrong in `boost::atomic`. So we replaced all `boost::atomic` with `std::atomic`. It worked!